# transporting crash log of my app to my server

Tags: iphone

Is there a way to send take the crash logs of my app send it to my server ? If no is there a alternative mechanism to do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While i don't want to advertise products in here, a lot of our iPhone Projects make use of the [Flurry Service](http://www.flurry.com/) . It is rather simple to integrate into your project (add library, one single method must be called). After integrating the flurry libraries and calls the app will send reports from the last session everytime it is started.

maybe that helps.